# Separate assigned values in SQL queries with regex

Tags: php, regex

What I need is to get all the assigned values in a SQL queries. I am only interested in strings and numbers. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ((name="alex" AND age >= 24) OR gender =1) 
AND date = CURDATE() ORDER BY active = 1 LIMIT 1
```

By using PHP's `preg_match` I would like to get an array containing the following values:

```
$values = array(
    'alex'// name , 
    24    //age, 
    1     //gender,
    1     //active
);
```

I am a beginner with regular expressions and all I have is this:

```
preg_match_all('/\=\s*?(.*)\s*/', $sqlquery, $matches);
```

which will return a single match, the one after the first operator found

Comment: Well, I do not think that using the regex to do this is wise. What do you think of using a sql-parser?

Comment: I was thinking about sending them as parameters for the `PDO::execute` function

Comment: 24 is not an assigned value here. It is a value for comparison.

Comment: but for the `PDO::exec` function you will need a SQL query. Why do you want to extract the values first? Do you want to create a new query with them?

Comment: @PascalRosin, sorry, I meant `PDO::execute`. I get the values, I create the parameters then replace the values by the parameters name. This changed query (with parameters name inside) and the parameters values are then sent.

Comment: @ali then your SQL query will always be the same except for the values. Because if not, you cannot be sure that the variables will be bound to the matching parameter in the prepared SQL query. So if the query is always of the same structure, your regex will be much simpler. just replace the values with `.*?`. The `?` is for not beeing greedy and maybe replace the optional whitespaces with `\s*`. And of course you will need to escape paranthesis. This way you can also detect SQL queries with a non-matching structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*[><!]?=\s*(["a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\)|\s|$)/
```

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Matches the left side of the equals to
- `\s*` Matches zero or more spaces.
- `[><!]?` Character class, matches `>` or `<` or `!`

  - `?` Quantifier, ensures that the preceding character class occures zero or one time.
- `=` Matches the space.
- `(["a-zA-Z0-9]+)` Matches the right hand side of equals.
- `(?=\)|\s|$)` Positive look ahead. Checks if the right hand side of `=` is followed by `\s` or `)` or end of string `$`

**Test**

```
$string = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ((name="alex" AND age >= 24) OR gender =1) 
AND date = CURDATE() ORDER BY active = 1 LIMIT 1';

preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*[><!]?=\s*(["a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\)|\s|$)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
// Outputs
// Array ( [0] => "alex" 
//         [1] => 24 
//         [2] => 1 
//         [3] => 1 )
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+ Matches the left side of the equals to ` `(["a-zA-Z0-9]+) Matches the right hand side of equals` means?

Comment: @papsk In expression `x = 132`: `x` - left side of the equals, `123` - right side of the equals

Comment: @papsk That is for `name="alex"` then `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` would match `name` (left of `=`) and the `["a-zA-Z0-9]+` will match `"alex"`. Hope its clear now

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
[=>!<]\s?([\w"'\d\s]+(?:\(\))?)
|____| |  |________|  |_____|
 Assign| op   |          |
    optional s|pace  Optional function call
          Any word, number, ", ' and space
```

But why do you want that? Maybe you can make that from PHP side without parsing SQL?

Comment: I would like to send those values as parameters for `PDO::execute()`. i thought it would be the fastest way. No complicated objects, just send the query as it is and the parser would "intelligently" get the parameterizable values.

Comment: @ali But if you already have them in queries, than it will throw errors as no such params found.